# Is there an extension for this-joomla article

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I would like to insert a link, for example:

`<a href="http:/mysite.com/...article.php?id=100">President Bush resigned</a>`

to a news section `(width=100 height=200)` in my site's front page. The article content is certainly created in Joomla's article manager with appropriate section and category; and `President Bush resigned` as in the link is the article title.

My question is simple, is there an extension available for Joomla that allows me to do this: (create an article on one page then display the `title name` as an `href` in another)? I think this acts similar to a *news feed* but for internal use only. I don't have any idea how to acheive this. Hopefully someone could offer me a hint for me to go from here.

Comment: there is a news feed module that come standard with Joomla. You can select how many aticle titles you would like to show and so on.

Comment: thank you ;) so very much. I am heading into news feed now

Answer (score 0):

OK, yes you can do that simply, using a couple of approaches:

1. **Module** - create a **module** to display an *article list* and
   specify on which 'pages' (Menu Items) to display it.
2. **Menu item** - create a new **menu item** of type *category list*

Hope it helps,

Gez